# Create new product with same URL as deleted product?

Tags: magento-1.7, url, url-rewrite

We had to delete a product and re-add it because we needed to remove a configurable attribute but now when I try to add the new product and use the same URL it generates a Page Not Found error.

http://www.gmesupply.com/tower-climbing/1113193-dbisala-exofitnex

I have already went in and deleted all the old rewrites. Is there something else I need to delete so that it will allow me to use the same URL as the old product or will I be forced to create a rewrite for the old URL?

Comment: I went ahead and did a rewrite for now but I'm still interested to know if this is possible.